# Deleting the last four columns starting from specific row linux

Tags: awk

Here is part of my data

```
 759 L   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 760 Y   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 761 H   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 762 T   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 763 T   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 764 D   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 765 R   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 766 F   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 767 W   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 768 A   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 769 N   0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 770 C   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 771 L   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 772 G   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 773 Y   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 774 S   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 775 H   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 776 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 777 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 778 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 779 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 780 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 781 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 782 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 783 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 784 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 785 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 786 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to delete last four 0s starting from line 776 to the end so that the column number matches with the previous rows. The delimiters are whitespace. I know for all rows, I can use

```
cut -f 21-
```

but how to How can I make it with specific rows with whitespace as delimiter? Thanks

Comment: What programming languages are you considering? What have you tried? Please also read the description of the tag you applied. Further, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I suspect you just need `awk 'NR>775{NF=22}1' input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any POSIX awk, without changing any of the spacing before/after or between the remaining fields:

```
awk 'NR>775{sub(/([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){4}[[:space:]]*$/,"")} 1' file
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect. What is ^ meaning here? and why put 1 in the end before '?

Comment: And a following question: if I have multiple files in a directory look like this, and each file the starting row number that I want to change is different. Is there a quick way in linux to make this work instead of change NR>(a number) manually?

Comment: `^` means "not" in a bracket expression and `1` is the idiomatic way to tell awk to print the current line. Depends what you mean - ask a new question with its own sample input and expected output demonstrating your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If those are actual line numbers, then perhaps you just want:

```
awk 'NR>775{NF=22}1' input-file
```

If those numbers are not line numbers, but are data in the first column, then perhaps you want:

```
awk '$1>775{NF=22}1' input-file
```

Comment: shouldn't subtracting the 4 from NF be better? `{NF-=4}`

Comment: @xgadme That's reasonable as well.  Perhaps a better approach would be something like `awk 'NR==1{a=NF} NR > 775{NF=a}1`

Comment: in this case it is even better to use the first line as initial.

Comment: Reducing the value of NF is undefined behavior per POSIX so some awks will remove fields, some will ignore it, etc. The awks that do remove fields will change all other chains of white space to single blank chars on affected lines which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

for reasons unclear to me, I can only get to `NF = 22` for first half if I collapse the double space in between and ruin the formatting of it.

If you're *very* sure the `NF` counts are `22` and `26`, and will perfectly line up afterwards, then just do

> ```
> awk NF=22
> ```

clean and simple — no `regex`, no function calls, no array splits,  no state tracking, and no `C ? T : F`

To keep original formatting intact :

- approach 1 : ***really crude*** method of hard-coding in values :

> ```
> awk '2<NF && NF-=3*(775<NR)' FS='\\40'
> ```

- approach 2 : new `NF` using 1st row it sees :

> ```
> mawk '__<=_{ __=NF-!_ }+$_<776||NF=__' FS='[ ]' 
> gawk '__<=_? __=NF-!_ : NR<776||NF=__' FS='[ ]' # is 1st col 
>                                                 # same as NR ?
> ```

```
 759 L   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 760 Y   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 761 H   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 762 T   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 763 T   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 764 D   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 765 R   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 766 F   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 767 W   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 768 A   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 769 N   0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 770 C   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 771 L   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 772 G   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 773 Y   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 774 S   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 775 H   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 776 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 777 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 778 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 779 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 780 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 781 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 782 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 783 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 784 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 785 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 786 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```